# Migrate Existing Android App Backend to Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I would like to know if there is an easy way to migrate my existing Android app backend to Google App Engine? The app backend currently is using shared hosting CPanel, communicate between client and server using PHP and store data in MySQL.

I've read through many documents & tutorials about GAE and I believe GAE is most preferred for user who wants to build NEW application. I cant find any discussion about migrating an existing app to GAE. I just want to get some confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to move to app engine - **yes**
**Will it be easy ?** - This will depend on your application and how its written. If your application is written in modules, means it will be very easy.

google provide cloud sql which is identical to mysql - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

Comment: But still, I guess at least need to re-generate the android project in GAE compatible environment and also rewrote those communication layer that I am using now between app client and CPanel PHP right?